# How to determine the exact value of $\sin(585^\circ)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm clueless on this question. Could someone explain how to do it?

Comment: are you calculating in degrees or radians ?

Comment: I'm calculating in degrees.

Comment: 585=360+120+60+45.

Comment: Now it is easy with that decomposition.

Comment: I can do it even with subtraction, look! 585=720-180+45 ;-D

Comment: If you measure angles in degrees you should write $\sin(585^\circ)$ instead of "sin585".

Comment: Not every one knows how to put the mathematical symbols like that it would be helpfull if some one provided a guidance

Comment: In the FAQ section there are directions how to use LaTeX in this site to properly write mathematics.

Comment: @missledragon : if you write an angle without a degree symbol then it is in radians, regardless of what you are thinking.  I penalize my students when they omit the degree symbol (except for the angle $0$, which is the same in radians and degrees.  For some nonzero numbers $x$, $\sin(x^\circ) = \sin(x)$ and  $\cos(x^\circ) = \cos(x)$, but these are very special numbers and I haven't figured out yet what they are.

Comment: @Stefan Smith Where did you get information about those numbers that have equal value of sine and/or cosine irrespectively of the representation in degrees or in radians?

Comment: @Thus See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x*2+pi%2F360%29%3Dsin%28x%29).

Comment: @Gugg Oh, I forgot to ask Mr. Wolfram, I see now, and they are not especially special numbers (at least not to me). Just some irrationals in the world of irrationals.

Comment: @Gugg : Thanks, but I don't think this is enough if you want the sine _and_ cosine to be the same.  You need $\frac{2\pi}{360}x-x$ to be an integer multiple of $2\pi$, so $x$ has the form $\frac{360n\pi}{\pi-180}$ for some integer $n$ (Wolfram's first answer).  Wolfram's second answer doesn't work.

Comment: @Thus : see my comment to Gugg.

Comment: @StefanSmith I ignored/overlooked the cosine bit, perhaps because I didn't (and still don't) see the relevance of cos to (the stating of) the original question. [Wolfram with cosine now](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x*2+pi%2F360%29%3Dsin%28x%29%2Ccos%28x*2+pi%2F360%29%3Dcos%28x%29).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When calculating in degrees, $\sin$ is periodic with a period of 360 degrees. Hence
$$\sin(585^\circ)=\sin(225^\circ).$$
In particular, $\sin(x+180^\circ)=-\sin(x)$.
Hence $$\sin(225^\circ)=\sin(45^\circ+180^\circ)=-\sin(45^\circ).$$
On the other hand, we know that $\sin(45^\circ)=\cos(45^\circ)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.
Hence 
$$\sin(585^\circ)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

Answer (score 5):

$\sin (k)= \sin (360 ^\circ+k) \implies \sin(585^\circ)= \sin(225^\circ) $

$\sin (m)= -\sin (180^\circ+m) \implies \sin(180^\circ+45^\circ) =-\sin (45^\circ)$

Comment: Thats a funny implication ;)

Comment: That was a typo.:P

Comment: you should mention you once calculate in degrees and once in radians

Comment: Or even better, @Inceptio: don't mix both units.

Comment: Now, I chose degrees over radians.;)

Answer (score 3):

I find the circle to be a great way to understand this -

[image]

Since the sine function is repetitive, in a 360 degree cycle, it's the same as 225 degrees.

I am 50, and don't recall using this circle in trig class. It's a great way to visualize the function for both Sine and Cosine and can easily be memorized if need be.

Answer (score 2):

One liner:

$\sin(585^\circ) = \sin(585^\circ-720^\circ) = \sin(-135^\circ) = \sin(-(90^\circ+45^\circ)) = -\cos(45^\circ) = -1/\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 0):

NB - All angle references are in degrees...
Since sin function has a period of 360,
sin 585 = sin 225
        = sin(180+45)
        = sin180*cos45+cos180sin45
        = 0+ -1*1/sqrt(2)
        = -1/sqrt(2)

Comment: In the FAQ section there are directions how to use LaTeX in this site to properly write mathematics.

Comment: @DonAntonio...Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $585^\circ\equiv 225^\circ\pmod{360^\circ}=180^\circ+45^\circ$

$180^\circ<180^\circ+45^\circ<270^\circ$

So, $585^\circ$ lies in the $3$rd Quadrant.

Using [All-Sin-Tan-Cos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Students_Take_Calculus) formula or [here](http://mathmistakes.info/facts/TrigFacts/learn/uc/sign.html), $\sin(585^\circ)<0$

Now, $585^\circ=90^\circ\cdot 6+45^\circ $

as the multiplicand of $90^\circ$ is even, sine will remain sine

So, $\sin(585^\circ)=\sin(90^\circ\cdot 6+45^\circ)=-\sin45^\circ=-\frac1{\sqrt2}$